# Flextable set Column name

Tags: gwt

after I spend 2 hours for a simple task please help me:

How can I set a column name of a flextable?

Alternitvly you can prived me an example of any kind of table which has different Column names in GWT.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no built in headers in the flex table. It just displays tabular data.
However you can use FlexTable.setWidget() or FlexTable.setHTML to have your own headers